# I am trying to make a OBD logger for heavy-duty vehicles

Tags: can, obd

The thing is that I have to use one CAN transceiver and one CAN controller. Both have one interface (CANH and CANL). I use dip switches to route different CAN signals whenever I need to using a DIP switch. [image: vehicle]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Hi jsotola, the question is mentioned in the above picture. It is about implementing the termination resistors. Can I implement it before the DIP switch for each CAN signals or can I implement it between the DIP switch and the transceiver? Can I leave the CANH1 and CANL1 signal lines floating in case if I implement termination after the DIP switch?

Comment: CAN is a multi-drop network, why can you only have one transceiver?

Comment: @RonBeyer  I only have one CAN interface available in my CAN controller chip that goes in between the transceiver and the MCU. Therefore I can not connect more than one CAN signals to my controller. Right now, I have j1939, CAN1 and CAN2 signals are coming from the OBD port.